# Force browser to download file from node js response

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I am trying to download a file from remote URL using node js and send the     file to the browser. After the response returns to my front end code I want to automatically download it. Can someone help? Here is my code snippet:

```
Backend node js code I am using request to make the remote url call:
  var request = require('request');
  var config = req.param('config');
  res.setHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + config.fileName);
  request('http://' + config.hostname + ':' + config.port + config.path).pipe(res);

Front end code in angular 1.5x:
var config = {
          hostname: APP_CONFIG.API_HOST,
          port: APP_CONFIG.API_PORT,
          path: '/document,
          method: 'GET',
          fileName: row.Name,
          fileType: row.Type
        };

        $http.put('/getFileFromUrl', {
          config: config
        })
        .then(function onSuccess(res) {
          if (res.data !== null && res.data.error === undefined) {
            // .........what should I do here its not auto downloading
            if (APP_VARS.isLoader === true) {
              APP_VARS.isLoader = false;
              grxUI.loading.stop();
            }
          }
        })
```

Comment: The code uses `$http.put` but the method in the config is GET. What is your intention here? GET or PUT?

Comment: PUT is to route to node js server call and GET is to actually GET the file from remote URL

Comment: Client side can't force server side

Comment: I am trying to download the file that I read on node js from remote URL. I get the response and I chunk it to client side. All good - but how do I convert it to BLOB again so that I can create an A tag, createURL from the blob and call a.click() to download the file.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of a <kbd>Download</kbd> button that becomes active **after** the data is loaded from the server:

```
<a download="data_{{files[0].name}}" xd-href="data">
  <button ng-disabled="!data">Download</button>
</a>
```

The **`xdHref`** Directive

```
app.module("myApp").directive("xdHref", function() {
  return function linkFn (scope, elem, attrs) {
     scope.$watch(attrs.xdHref, function(newVal) {
       if (newVal) {
         elem.attr("href", newVal);
       }
     });
  };
});
```

The [DEMO on PLNKR.](https://plnkr.co/edit/BXSuqaQff928w3SQQ170?p=preview)

---

### Downloading Binary Files with AngularJS

When downloading binary files it is important to set the `responseType` attribute of the XHR.

```
var config = { responseType: 'blob' }

var httpPromise = $http.get(url, config);

httpPromise.then(function (response) {
    $scope.data = response.data;
});
```

For more information, see [MDN XHR API - ResponseType.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseType)

Comment: Thanks for your your quick response - its failing on PDF.

Comment: In fact I tried other file types such xls, doc etc. - they all failed. Can you please take a look at it?

Comment: Please see my comment for @ akinjide above